# Some websites can't be accessed only in computers, not phones

Tags: networking, ipconfig

My home network has 2 phones and 2 computers. On the phones any website can be accessed, but on the computers both of them can only access Google services (YouTube, Keep, GMail), Facebook & Messenger, Bing, Wikipedia, XDA forum, but can't access Reddit, Stack Exchange, or other websites I can think of/show up in Google search.

I don't understand why this can even be happen. I have contacted the ISP and they report that the signal is fine. I try `ipconfig /release`, and I have these error:

Computer 1:

```
No operation can be performed on Wireless Network Connection 2 while it has its media disconnected.
An error occurred while releasing interface Wireless Network Connection : The parameter is incorrect.

An error occurred while releasing interface Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 : The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Computer 2:

```
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Wireless Network Connection 8 while it has its media disconnected.
An error occurred while releasing interface Wireless Network Connection 7 : The parameter is incorrect.

An error occurred while releasing interface Wireless Network Connection : The parameter is incorrect.
```

There is no satisfactory solution I can find. I have also tried other suggestions in [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain/), but they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to my ISP technician (and through my forgetful and untrained mind), it's because my computers have conflicted IP, making the MAC addresses in the router stuck. It has to be reset several times to solve this.

The reason some pages can be loaded is because of the DNS. I don't really understand this part.